# Can't update React state hook from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I want to update my state hook with useEffect. Somehow it gives me an error and brokes my app.

Console.log gives right answer in console but somehow react doesn't want to recognize setCountries as a state hook function. What I am doing wrong here?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

var host = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all'

const App = () => {
    const { countries, setCountries } = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(host)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                setCountries(response.data)
            })
    })

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

And error I am getting in browser

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setCountries is not a function
```

error in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setCountries is not a function
    at App.js:14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: `useState` returns an array with two elements, and an array does not have a `countries` or `setCountries` key to destructure for. You could do this:

```
  const { 0: countries, 1: setCountries } = useState([]);
```

or just

```
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
```

Secondly, `useEffect(..)` without any second argument will cause the effect to be triggered *on every rerender*, so your component will get stuck in an update loop. Use an empty array as its second argument to only trigger the effect on load.